# JavaScript Max unsigned int 32?

Tags: javascript

I failed to find any constant in JS language which represents MAX UINT 32
Does it exists? I can have hardcoded the number itself, but i prefer to go in the more appropriate path of coding

Comment: Are you asking about `Number`s specifically or possibly [Typed Arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Typed_arrays)? `Number`s are [64-bit floating point](http://es5.github.io/#x4.3.19) -- they do not make a distinction for integers. Typed Arrays, however, do add support for 8- to 32-bit unsigned integers.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try This:

```
<script>
function myFunction()
{
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=Number.MAX_VALUE;
}
</script>
```

**Description**

The MAX_VALUE property has a value of approximately 1.79E+308. Values larger than MAX_VALUE are represented as "Infinity".

Because MAX_VALUE is a static property of Number, you always use it as Number.MAX_VALUE, rather than as a property of a Number object you created.

**Example: Using MAX_VALUE**

The following code multiplies two numeric values. If the result is less than or equal to MAX_VALUE, the func1 function is called; otherwise, the func2 function is called.

```
if (num1 * num2 <= Number.MAX_VALUE) {
   func1();
} else {
   func2();
}
```

Comment: @mplungjan this answer actually says that

Comment: Not when I commented and still not explicitly

Comment: Yes **I** do. People using w3schools as reference may not.

Answer (score 2):

For integers, [`Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER) would be appropriate, as it's the maximum safe integer in JavaScript (2^53 – 1).  The 53 power comes from [how the double-precision floating-point numbers work](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format). Those are also used in JavaScript to store numbers.

```js
// In the safe integers zone:

const a = Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER - 1; 
const b = Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER - 0;

console.log(a); // 9007199254740990
console.log(b); // 9007199254740991 (b + 1)
console.log(a === b); // false

// Outside the safe integers zone:

const x = Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER + 1;
const y = Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER + 2;

console.log(x); // 9007199254740992
console.log(y); // Also 9007199254740992, because precision....
console.log(x === y); // true
```

By the way, imagine that would happen if your iteration meets this kind of unsafe zone - infinite loop.

See also:

- [`Number.EPSILON`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/EPSILON) for the difference between 1 and the smallest floating point number greater than 1;
- [`Number.MAX_VALUE`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_VALUE) for maximal number representable in JavaScript - not integer, but floating point.
- [`Number.MIN_SAFE_INTEGER`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MIN_SAFE_INTEGER) - for minimal safe integer (negative) in JavaScript.
- [`Number.MIN_VALUE`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MIN_VALUE) - for minimal negative number overall (floating point).
- In some cases it's nicer to just use use [`Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/POSITIVE_INFINITY) (or [`Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/NEGATIVE_INFINITY) for negative), like when finding max/min values - for empty set you would get this not quite valid numerical value, that you can more easily notice and understand.
- On linked pages you can also find other interesting stuff, like [`Number.isSafeInteger`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isSafeInteger) function to check whenever number is safe integer.

Answer (score 0):

javascript was no ints every number is a floating point number which is of class Number. The max value of that is `Number.MAX_VALUE` but that is almost certainly not what you are looking for (`Number.MAX_VALUE = 1.7976931348623157e+308`)

Comment: Not "decimal", just "floating point". They are stored in binary.

Comment: @JanDvorak I was just saying that they look like decimals not referencing the internal storage methods, but I will correct it

Answer (score -1):

It does not exist, however you can have Max Numeric Value returned by `Number` object

You can see it here

```
alert(Number.MAX_VALUE);
```

1. [Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_VALUE)

Comment: This is not an integer, javascript only has one class for numbers which is Number

Comment: Look at the result of `Number.MAX_VALUE` and you will understand the problem with your answer

Comment: @mplungjan have a look at Reference Number 1

Comment: @mplungjan downvotes are not an issue. OP stated `I can have hardcoded the number itself, but i prefer to go in the more appropriate path of coding`: According to my little knowledge there is no other such constant in JavaScript which returns the max INT limit. Hence this answer